# Cloning a C drive - boot partitions

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, mbr

I have a small C drive with W10 on it on Disc 0, and a D drive with data on it on Disc 1.

I want to move C to a partition on Disc 1 and test Ubuntu on Disc 0.

Both discs have a recovery partition, and a boot/MBR partition before the respective C/D partitions.

What do I need to end up with regarding the boot/MBR partitions, and how do I get there?

Comment: As chances are good to break the windows OS as well as the ubuntu you want to install, first create backups of your data. Second, i'd suggest not to move around windows, but make place on your data disc (resizing the data partition, creating free space to install ubuntu on it) and install ubuntu there. just a thought, it would be easier that way.

Comment: I suggest you add a disk management screenshot of current situation.

Comment: Thanks both! Your input helped me see through the mist and I've just thought of a simple way to get what I want (though a little time consuming). 1) Backup the data disc. 2) Clean the disc and clone the C drive onto it. 3) Create a new partition in the unused space and recover the data disc onto it from the backup. It will all be exactly how I want it then and the boot sector etc will all be correct.